# Rock,paper,scissors game animation.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my rock,paper, scissors game. http://jsfiddle.net/Renay/hL3j5hm6/6/

```
    <html> </html>
```

How do i go about adding an animation where before the result is given, there is a 3,2,1 countdown while the images are bouncing up and down. I've tried adding various functions but nothing has seemed to worked. I'm not too sure how to go about adding movement to images and where abouts it would go in my script.

In steps :

- User choice is selected(rock/paper/scissors button)
- *Countdown begins*
- *Two hand symbols start bouncing up and down*
- *Computer and User choices are shown under images.*
- Result is shown

Steps that are in italic is what i am having trouble with.

I know the CSS isn't ideal but i'll fix that up after i get the functioning right.

Any sort of help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please copy the source code from jsfiddle into your question.  One day the fiddle may go away. Posts must be designed to stay useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what I came up with.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48yw4y80/)

#### HTML:

```
<div id='computerSide'>
    <h1> Computer </h1>
    <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/sv6ieobip/rock1.png" id="rockOne" height="130" width="130" class='compFist' />
    <div id="you"></div>
</div>
<div id='playerSide'>
     <h1> You </h1>
    <img src="http://s28.postimg.org/syouexkjx/rock2.png" id="rockOne" height="130" width="130" class='compFist' />
    <div id="comp"></div>
</div>
<div id="countDown"></div>
<div id='instructions'>
     <h2> Choose your weapon! </h2>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id='buttons'>
        <input type='button' value='Rock' id='rockB' class='button1' />
        <input type='button' value='Paper' id='paperB' class='button1' />
        <input type='button' value='Scissors' id='scissorsB' class='button1' />
        <input type='button' value='Replay' id='replayButton' />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="yourResult"></div>
<div id="compResult"></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var rockButton = document.getElementById('rockB');
var paperButton = document.getElementById('paperB');
var scissorsButton = document.getElementById('scissorsB');
var replayButton = document.getElementById('replayButton');
var result = document.getElementById('yourResult');
var cresult = document.getElementById('compResult');
var num = document.getElementById('countDown');
var you = document.getElementById('you');
var comp = document.getElementById('comp');
var win = 'You Won!<br />';
var lose = 'You Lost!<br />';
var tie = 'Tie!<br />';
var r = 'Rock!';
var p = 'Paper!';
var s = 'Scissors!';
var compChoice;

function randChoice() {
    var shuffle = Math.random();
    if (shuffle <= 0.34) {
        return 'rock';
    } else if (shuffle <= 0.67) {
        return 'paper';
    } else {
        return 'scissors';
    }
}

function main(w, one, two, three, four, five, six) {
    you.innerHTML = '';
    comp.innerHTML = '';
    result.innerHTML = '';
    cresult.innerHTML = '';
    num.innerHTML = "3";
    $('img').animate({'top': '20px'}, "fast");
    $('img').animate({'top': '0px'}, function() {
        num.innerHTML = "2";
    });
    $('img').animate({'top': '20px'}, "fast");
    $('img').animate({'top': '0px'}, function() {
        num.innerHTML = "1";
    });
    $('img').animate({'top': '20px'}, "fast");
    $('img').animate({'top': '0px'}, function() {
        num.innerHTML = "";
        you.innerHTML = w;
        compChoice = randChoice();
        if (compChoice == 'rock') {
            comp.innerHTML = r;
            result.innerHTML = one;
            cresult.innerHTML = two;
        } else if (compChoice == 'paper') {
            comp.innerHTML = p;
            result.innerHTML = three;
            cresult.innerHTML = four;
        } else {
            comp.innerHTML = s;
            result.innerHTML = five;
            cresult.innerHTML = six;
        }
    });
}

rockButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    main(r, tie, tie, lose, win, win, lose);
});

paperButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    main(p, win, lose, tie, tie, lose, win);
});

scissorsButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    main(s, lose, win, win, lose, tie, tie);
});

replayButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

#### CSS:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#buttons {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#playerSide {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#computerSide {
    float:right;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#instructions {
    padding: 0 0 0 40%;
}
.button1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
input[type=button] {
    background-color:#FFFACD;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width:6em;
    height:2em;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.compWeapon {
    margin: 20% 0 0 45%;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#replayButton {
    background-color: #FFD700;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
    color: black;
}
#yourResult {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#compResult {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    right: 15%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#yourResult, #compResult {
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    position: relative;
}
#countDown {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 50%;
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#you {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 53%;
    left: 4%;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#comp {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 53%;
    right: 10%;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```